# Unable to add new 2019 HyperV node to 2012R2 HyperV Cluster

Tags: cluster, failovercluster, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, windows-cluster, windows-server-2019

I could really use some help here. I evicted an failed HyperV node from our 2 node 2012R2 Hyper-V cluster. The node has been rebuilt with server 2019 and am trying to re-inject it back into the cluster.

**NOTE1:** The host was rebuilt using the same node name.

**NOTE2:** The network adaptor(s) layout is is slightly different however communication is working from all adaptors.

When i try to add the node i get the following error:

'Cluster service on node SERVER2 did not reach the running state. The error code is **0x5b4**. For more information check the cluster log and the system event log from node SERVER2. This operation returned because the timeout period expired.'

In the FailoverClustering event log i see:

*cxl::ConnectWorker::operator (): HrError(0x00000002)' because of '[SV] Schannel Authentication or Authorization Failed'*

*mscs_security::SchannelSecurityContext::AuthenticateAndAuthorize: (2)' because of 'Cluster certificate doesn't exist'*

I did a search for the above errors however none of the below has worked:

1. Confirmed i am am able to ping the hosts via the managment,
   production, clustercommunication and livemigration network
   interfaces.
2. Confirmed iSCSI could connect to CSV volumes
3. Ensured IPV6 is enabled
4. Ensured the DCHP client service is running
5. Ensured the system could access the QUORUM witness (able to write to
   the directory)
6. Checked *'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' to check for 'DisabledComponents'*
7. Did a search in AD for a duplicate computer account hostname matching the the node to be added.
8. Tried re-adding the node at least 12 times
9. Checked the registry path *'Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography`* to ensure the Crypto RSA MachineKey within *'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys'* matched the GUID.

I am lost of ideas, the only unique thing here is that i am trying to add a 2019 Hyper-V node to a 2012R2 node Hyper-V cluster.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's doubtful that Windows Server 2019 is a supported OS for a node in a 2012 R2 based cluster.

Comment: How does one upgrade their cluster to 2019?
Is an in-place upgrade the only path?

Comment: You can perform a rolling cluster upgrade from 2012 R2 to 2016. You'd then need to do a rolling upgrade from 2016 to 2019. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/cluster-operating-system-rolling-upgrade

Comment: All - Joeqwerty was correct. I rebuilt the node to 2016 and all is working.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted.